# PHP unserialize fails with non-encoded characters?

Tags: php, character, encode, serialization

```
$ser = 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"héllö";i:1;s:5:"wörld";}'; // fails
$ser2 = 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"hello";i:1;s:5:"world";}'; // works
$out = unserialize($ser);
$out2 = unserialize($ser2);
print_r($out);
print_r($out2);
echo "<hr>";
```

But why?
Should I encode before serialzing than? How?

I am using Javascript to write the serialized string to a hidden field, than PHP's $_POST
In JS I have something like:

```
function writeImgData() {
    var caption_arr = new Array();
    $('.album img').each(function(index) {
         caption_arr.push($(this).attr('alt'));
    });
    $("#hidden-field").attr("value", serializeArray(caption_arr));
};
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The reason why `unserialize()` fails with:

```
$ser = 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"héllö";i:1;s:5:"wörld";}';
```

Is because the length for `héllö` and `wörld` are wrong, since PHP doesn't correctly handle multi-byte strings natively:

```
echo strlen('héllö'); // 7
echo strlen('wörld'); // 6
```

However if you try to `unserialize()` the following correct string:

```
$ser = 'a:2:{i:0;s:7:"héllö";i:1;s:6:"wörld";}';

echo '<pre>';
print_r(unserialize($ser));
echo '</pre>';
```

It works:

```
Array
(
    [0] => héllö
    [1] => wörld
)
```

If you use PHP `serialize()` it should correctly compute the lengths of multi-byte string indexes.

On the other hand, if you want to work with serialized data in multiple (programming) languages you should forget it and move to something like JSON, which is way more standardized.

Comment: json_encode: "This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data..." http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: and in the case where you're using serialize( ) and unserialize( ) is still failing, check your storage medium. i.e. mysql you should store as binary or blob. If you store as text in mysql it won't handle your multibyte chars.

Comment: Also be careful when switching between php environments.  I ran into issues encoding on a local machine before saving to the database and then trying to unserialize on the live server.  Adjusting character counts for the characters solved the problem.

Comment: This is probably also the answer to a problem I had about two years ago and never found an answer to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289218/visually-same-string-gives-different-var-dumps-in-php

Answer (score 52):

I know this was posted like one year ago, but I just have this issue and come across this, and in fact I found a solution for it. This piece of code works like charm!

The idea behind is easy. It's just helping you by recalculating the length of the multibyte strings as posted by @Alix above.

A few modifications should suits your code:

```
/**
 * Mulit-byte Unserialize
 *
 * UTF-8 will screw up a serialized string
 *
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

Source: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6592

Tested on my machine, and it works like charm!!

Comment: in my case the problem was in database encoding, so i lost part of my data in `???`, but this function helps me to make code work even with this, thanks

Comment: Just saved me a massive headache! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for this very useful work. I tested it as well and it works for me on UTF-8 data with French accents (PHP 5.3 on my server).

Comment: @Sébastien Check out another answer here that points out that there might be issue with this approach ;)

Comment: Good catch, I would not have spotted that. +1 for @Joe-Hong as well. Is there a way to check and correct for that?

Comment: Note that the `e` modifier is going away, time to switch to preg_replace_callback.

Comment: In addition to the "e" modifier going away, this will fail on any string that was serialized containing the end of the regexp search (";)

Comment: This function just saved my day! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've post below your function changed to work with PHP 5.5. Thanks for your useful contribution.

Comment: Actually the Regular Expression is wrong, as the string itself may include the pattern that is not related to the serialization schema. E.g. The serialized part `...s:28:"some "quotes"; in the middle";...` after your function will return `...s:13:"some \"quotes"; in the middle";...`. That's one of the reasons the serializations has been created at the first place.

Comment: AWSOME @lionel-chan I was so tensed thinking all data went corrupt. You saved my life......thank you so much......:):):). THIS SHOWULD HAVE BEEN CORRECT ACCEPTED ANSWER

Answer (score 37):

[Lionel Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534862/lionel-chan) answer modified to work with PHP >= 5.5 :

```
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string2 = preg_replace_callback(
        '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',
        function($m){
            $len = strlen($m[2]);
            $result = "s:$len:\"{$m[2]}\";";
            return $result;

        },
        $string);
    return unserialize($string2);
}
```

This code uses *preg_replace_callback* as [*preg_replace* with the /e modifier is obsolete](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) since PHP 5.5.

Comment: I had to use this version to prevent HTML strings in encoded arrays from getting incorrectly escaped double quotes in unserialized strings.

Comment: A million thanks @David. I've been struggling with converting this function for many days now!

Answer (score 10):

The issue is - *as pointed out by Alix* - related to encoding.

Until PHP 5.4 the internal encoding for PHP was ISO-8859-1, this encoding uses a single byte for some characters that in unicode are multibyte. The result is that multibyte values serialized on UTF-8 system will not be readable on ISO-8859-1 systems.

**The avoid problems like this make sure all systems use the same encoding:**

```php
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$arr = array('foo' => 'bár');
$buf = serialize($arr);
```

**You can use `utf8_(encode|decode)` to cleanup:**

```php
// Set system encoding to iso-8859-1
mb_internal_encoding('iso-8859-1');
$arr = unserialize(utf8_encode($serialized));
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

In reply to @Lionel above, in fact the function mb_unserialize() as you proposed won't work if the serialized string itself contains char sequence  `";` (quote followed by semicolon). 
Use with caution. For example:

```
$test = 'test";string'; 
// $test is now 's:12:"test";string";'
$string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $test);
print $string; 
// output: s:4:"test";string";  (Wrong!!)
```

JSON is the ways to go, as mentioned by others, IMHO

Note: I post this as new answer as I don't know how to reply directly (new here).

Comment: You'll be able to reply with comments soon.  Keep contributing!  Cheers~

Comment: Good to know. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** use PHP serialization/unserialization when the other end is not PHP. It is not meant to be a portable format - for example, it even includes ascii-1 characters for protected keys which is nothing you want to deal with in javascript (even though it would work perfectly fine, it's just extremely ugly).

Instead, use a portable format like *JSON*. XML would do the job, too, but JSON has less overhead and is more programmer-friendly as you can easily parse it into a simple data structure instead of having to deal with XPath, DOM trees etc.

Comment: Not to mention unserializing from untrusted sources can cause arbitrary code execution.

Comment: Unfortunately the choice has been imposed on us by someone else's work. This is particularly common when importing data from an older project/system whereby serialisation is already well established in its data.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:

```
$unserialized = unserialize(utf8_encode($st));
```

Answer (score 1):

One more slight variation here which will hopefully help someone ... I was serializing an array then writing it to a database. On retrieving the data the unserialize operation was failing.

It turns out that the database longtext field I was writing into was using latin1 not UTF8. When I switched it round everything worked as planned.

Thanks to all above who mentioned character encoding and got me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use javascript to encode as json and then use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) to unserialize.

Comment: that said, $ser = 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"héllö";i:1;s:5:"wörld";}';
var_dump(unserialize($ser)); works fine with me. What do you mean by fail? The call to unserialize() fails?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * MULIT-BYTE UNSERIALIZE
 *
 * UTF-8 will screw up a serialized string
 *
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se/', function($matches) { return 's:'.strlen($matches[1]).':"'.$matches[1].'";'; }, $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can break the string down to an array:**

```
$finalArray = array();
$nodeArr = explode('&', $_POST['formData']);

foreach($nodeArr as $value){
    $childArr = explode('=', $value);
    $finalArray[$childArr[0]] = $childArr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize:

```
foreach ($income_data as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = urlencode($value);
}
$data_str = serialize($income_data);
```

Unserialize:

```
$data = unserialize($data_str);
foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = urldecode($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me.

```
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/s:([0-9]+):"(.*?)";/',
        function ($match) {
            return "s:".strlen($match[2]).":\"".$match[2]."\";"; 
        },
        $string
    );
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with **line endings** (likely some editor have changed my file from DOS to Unix).

I put together these apadtive wrappers:

```
function unserialize_fetchError($original, &$unserialized, &$errorMsg) {
    $unserialized = @unserialize($original);
    $errorMsg = error_get_last()['message'];
    return ( $unserialized !== false || $original == 'b:0;' );  // "$original == serialize(false)" is a good serialization even if deserialization actually returns false
}

function unserialize_checkAllLineEndings($original, &$unserialized, &$errorMsg, &$lineEndings) {
    if ( unserialize_fetchError($original, $unserialized, $errorMsg) ) {
        $lineEndings = 'unchanged';
        return true;
    } elseif ( unserialize_fetchError(str_replace("\n", "\n\r", $original), $unserialized, $errorMsg) ) {
        $lineEndings = '\n to \n\r';
        return true;
    } elseif ( unserialize_fetchError(str_replace("\n\r", "\n", $original), $unserialized, $errorMsg) ) {
        $lineEndings = '\n\r to \n';
        return true;
    } elseif ( unserialize_fetchError(str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $original), $unserialized, $errorMsg) ) {
        $lineEndings = '\r\n to \n';
        return true;
    } //else
    return false;
}
```