# PHP unserialize function always returns 1

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

**Well**, I made a code that returns that serializated data:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:250:"Sistema Operativo: Windows Vista SP1 / Windows XP SP3
Procesador: Intel Core 2 Duo 1.8 Ghz, AMD Athlon X2 64 2.4 Ghz
Memoria: 1.5GB Windows Vista / 1GB Windows XP
Espacio en Disco: 16GB libres
GrÃ¡fica: 256MB NVIDIA 7900 / 256MB ATI X1900";i:1;s:281:"Sistema Operativo: Windows Vista SP1 / Windows XP SP3
MicroProcesador: Intel Core 2 Quad 2.4Ghz, AMD Phenom X3 2.1Ghz
RAM: 2.5GB Windows Vista / 2.5GB Windows XP
Espacio en Disco: 18GB libres
GrÃ¡fica: 512 MB NVIDIA 8600 / 512MB ATI 3870
Otros: DVD-ROM de doble capa";i:2;s:0:"";}
```

But when I unserialize it, it only returns 1...

I don't know why...

I use `$data = (array)unserialize($quote);` but I had that weird problem that I don't know how to solve... :'(

**EDIT:**

There is my serialized variable `$finalreq = serialize(array(0 => $minreq, 1 => $req, 2 => $maxreq));` $minreq, $req and $maxreq is a $_POST variable.

**SOLVED:**

If it happens to you the only thing you have to do is use a special function for UTF-8 characters called muti-byte unserialization.

The code:

```
/**
 * Mulit-byte Unserialize
 *
 * UTF-8 will screw up a serialized string
 *
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

The original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813058/3286975

**Thanks.**

Comment: Is your string ok? I have: `PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 266 of 551 bytes`

Comment: I echo it before, and It returns me that... But any errors appears at unserialization of that string it only returns 1. :(

Comment: Please check if `serialize($your_object);` is the same string as above.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually returning `false`, because it's throwing an error:

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 266 of 551 bytes
```

`var_dump`-ing the results returns  `bool(false)` due to the error.

Did you alter the information after serializing? Serialized data is picky.  In your data above:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:250:
```

1. The `a:3` says "it's an array, with 3 elements"
2. The `{` indicates the start of the first element.
3. The `i:0` indicates the index is zero.
4. The `s:250` indicates that the next 250 characters are the value.

If you've changed the length in any way, the parser can't properly unserialize, because it's expecting 250 characters....

Comment: Its look like a bug, because I only use a serialize function for get that weird string... So what can I do?

Comment: I solved it using that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813058/3286975 Thanks anyway for the guide. :P