# PHP - Getting bool(false) when using unserialize

Tags: php, serialization

The $response I am getting from the server is shown below:-

```
a:2:{s:3:"Car";s:0:"";s:9:"JbMessage";s:0:"";s:10:"PreBooking";s:0:"";s:6:"pickup";s:36:"TOWNEND CENTRE; WORKSOP ROAD S26 4WB";s:4:"Zone";s:8:"OOA_EAST";s:7:"dropoff";s:41:"PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD; LOUGHBOROUGH LE115GU";s:8:"PassName";s:0:"";s:8:"Customer";s:0:"";s:9:"AccountNo";s:0:"";s:8:"DocketNo";s:0:"";s:3:"Tel";s:0:"";s:7:"CarType";s:3:"Car";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";s:9:"Comments1";s:0:"";s:9:"OrderedBy";s:0:"";s:12:"Autorization";s:0:"";s:8:"BookedBy";s:0:"";s:15:"BookingDateTime";s:19:"11042014 09:31:49";s:10:"Dispatched";s:10:"01011900";s:5:"Miles";s:5:"43.21";s:6:"Driver";s:0:"";s:7:"Payment";s:4:"Cash";s:8:"Priority";s:1:"1";s:4:"Done";s:1:"C";s:11:"JourneyType";s:0:"";s:12:"NoPassengers";s:1:"1";s:5:"Drops";s:0:"";s:2:"TM";s:0:"";s:14:"BookingMethode";s:5:"Phone";s:7:"Editted";s:0:"";s:9:"EdittedOn";s:10:"01011900";s:9:"FromHouse";s:0:"";s:6:"FromNo";s:0:"";s:10:"FromStreet";s:28:"TOWNEND CENTRE; WORKSOP ROAD";s:10:"FromZoneNo";s:2:"73";s:12:"FromPostCode";s:7:"S26 4WB";s:10:"FromEWGrid";s:0:"";s:12:"emailAddress";s:0:"";s:9:"FromNotes";s:0:"";s:11:"AutorizedBy";s:0:"";s:7:"ToHouse";s:0:"";s:4:"ToNo";s:0:"";s:8:"ToStreet";s:33:"PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD; LOUGHBOROUGH";s:8:"ToZoneNo";s:2:"73";s:10:"ToPostCode";s:7:"LE115GU";s:6:"Mobile";s:0:"";s:7:"ToNotes";s:0:"";s:8:"ToEWGrid";s:0:"";s:11:"BookingDate";s:19:"11042014 09:31:00";s:10:"DriverFare";s:4:"71.5";s:12:"CustomerFare";s:4:"71.5";s:12:"DriverExtras";s:1:"0";s:14:"CustomerExtras";s:1:"0";s:11:"WaitingTime";s:0:"";s:
```

I am doing the following:-

```
$response = strip_tags($response);
$deserializedAddressArray = stripslashes($response);
$deserializedAddressArray = unserialize($response);

var_dump($deserializedAddressArray);
```

However, I don't understand why `$deserializedAddressArray` is coming back as bool(false), any ideas?

Comment: I ran your code and i got `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 46 of 1495 bytes`.  Are you sure your serialized string is valid?

Comment: That response looks truncated, ending in `;s:`

Comment: Yes, string says, "I have two length element" `a:2`, but there is not even an element in serialized string. String was truncated

Comment: Well thats the answer then. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php, according to the return value, it will be false if the string is invalid and throw a NOTICE.  Apparently you have notice errors switch off otherwise you would have spotted that.

Answer (score 0):

Your serialize data is not valid. Please make sure that you give the right string. there is no   ending bracket in it for example valid serialize string

```
 a:1:{s:4:"name";s:6:"testing";}
```

This is the valid serialize string with the ending bracket

Answer (score 0):

So we know the string is invalid, but as a stab in the dark this may have one of the following causes:

- If the string is stored against a table, then the column type should be `long text` to ensure the highly variable string length will be stored.
- If any of the data being serialized contains non-encoded characters, or multi-byte characters, it is possible for the string to end with one of those characters.
  [PHP unserialize fails with non-encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853454/php-unserialize-fails-with-non-encoded-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Got this working, the problem was at the start `a:2:` - as soon as I changed this to `a:77:` it started working.

This is because there are 77 values in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the size of your table in the database.
Example: varchar 255 to varchar 510 Or Change type to TEXT.