# Visually same string gives different var_dumps in php

Tags: php, string, var-dump

**UPDATE:** Anwer is here [PHP unserialize fails with non-encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853454/php-unserialize-fails-with-non-encoded-characters)

I'm trying to match objects with in_array. This works fine except for the object with this string as a property. Visually they are the same, but when I do a var_dump PHP sees different lengths.

var_dump results:

```
string(26) "Waar    zijn mijn centjes"
string(31) "Waar    zijn mijn centjes"
```

What can be the cause? Some ascii value I don't know of?

Comment: Did you looked into the source code?, some hidden character, spaces ?!

Comment: it is because of UTF. Eg. this `var_dump("åèö");` results in this `string(6) "Ã¥Ã¨Ã¶" ` So I think you can't compare them visually.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. But how do I fix it? How get I get PHP to give me "true" when I call in_array

Comment: somewhere seen. Try this: in_array( mb_strtolower($str, "UTF-8"), $arr)

Comment: Using that on both the needle and when the array is made (so both are UTF-8) doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: @Rizier123: I did. They both have a tab and \n\r at the end

Comment: try outputting the string with bin2hex and you'll see the difference

Comment: That gives me different values indeed. But the question remains unanswered.

Ik take a value from a txt file. Then insert it in the database. When it comes back from the DB the string doesn't match with the original value from the file. They have different lengths although the first thing I do after reading them from the file is encoding them to UTF-8.

My problem is that I want my strings to match. I don't what to see that they are different. I want to let them match.

Comment: Please post the two results from bin2hex here

Comment: 57616172097a696a6e206d696a6e2063656e746a6573f09f91bc
AND
57616172097a696a6e206d696a6e2063656e746a657326237831663437633b

Comment: Could creating a hash for the content work? Hoping the hash doesn't change and than just compare hashes?

Comment: Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853454/php-unserialize-fails-with-non-encoded-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the hex dump of your strings:

```
57616172097a696a6e206d696a6e2063656e746a6573f09f91bc
```

and

```
57616172097a696a6e206d696a6e2063656e746a657326237831663437633b
```

As we can clearly see, there's only a difference in the end: `f09f91bc` becomes `26237831663437633b`.

So what's the difference?

`f09f91bc` is the hex representation of `U+1F47C BABY ANGEL character (&#x1F47C;)`, so that one is perfect UTF-8.

But `26237831663437633b` isn't UTF-8 anymore, the string is actually ASCII and translates to `&#x1f47c;`, so it's simply HTML's numeric character reference of the baby angel character.

So the angel must have somewhere been translated to its HTML numeric character reference and that is not something that happens just when writing and reading from a file or a DB. I'd guess it has happened somewhere in your output processing.

You may use `html_entity_decode` to translate the HTML entities back to their UTF-8 equivalent:

```php
$a = html_entity_decode('Waar    zijn mijn centjes&#x1f47c;');
$b = 'Waar    zijn mijn centjes';
var_dump($a === $b);
```

See http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/n6t1-d9w7 to try the code.

Comment: OK. First of all. Thank you so much for your time. I think thit is something Wordpress does automatically. Do you know of any way to change it back from ASCII to UTF-8?

Comment: @MarcvanNieuwenhuijzen do you need anything else to answer your question?

Comment: Sad to say that isn't the solution either

Comment: @MarcvanNieuwenhuijzen I've added code to my answer. It appears to work for the given strings. Where doesn't it work?

Comment: You Sir, are my absolute hero today. I'm not sture why it didn't work on my last try. I think that I maybe used html_entitity_decode twice so the decoded string was again decoded. But. IT IS WORKING NOW! Thank you so much for your time, effort en wits

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case:

```
$plan_name: string(29) "check-up & template optimizer"
$cell_comp: string(33) "check-up & template optimizer"
```

The problem here was the '&' which in the 1st string was being seen as an **HTML** character and in the 2nd string was seen as an **ASCII** entity.

If you don't understand the difference, take a look here (see the difference between 'Symbol' and 'HTML Number' columns): https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

**The solution:** Applying on both strings the same function, which can be:

- either converting the ASCII entities to their corresponding character: **html_entity_decode()**
- either converting the HTML characters to their corresponding ASCII entities: **htmlentities()**

Here is how the final result looked for me:

```
$plan_name = html_entity_decode( strtolower( sanitize_text_field($key) ) );
$cell_comp = html_entity_decode( strtolower( sanitize_text_field($cell_2) ) );

if( $plan_name == $cell_comp ) :
 ...
endif;
```