# unserialize(): Error at offset 20 of 37 bytes

Tags: php, serialization

i am trying to `unserialize()` this string `a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Plzeň";i:1;s:5:"Jiné";}`

Code is as simple as it can be:

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Plzeň";i:1;s:5:"Jiné";}'));
```

However I get an error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 20 of 37 bytes in
>   response is:

```
bool(false)
```

I already check some articles and other post here in stackoverflow but I dont have any slashes or other things which were recomanded to remove before unserialize. If I unserialize online on page : https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html it return correct values. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853454/php-unserialize-fails-with-non-encoded-characters

Comment: I am able to serialize it perfectly, no errors. what is the php version you are using?

Comment: @Andurit everything is said in the related question, check it out

Comment: @Inurosen the question you link above looks similar as my problem, how ever I don't completly understand the answer. Problem is in length of words but dispite this fact I dont understand whats the change between "first" and "fixed" string in question

Comment: @Andurit, the difference is that corrected string is UTF-8.

Comment: Just find it, thank you guys :)

Comment: @Andurit Checkout the ` mb_unserialize` function in the related question